# CSS 100% height layout. Fluid header, footer and content. In IE10 and firefox

Tags: css

This works for Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/EtNgv/ I want to make it work in IE and Firefox.

Answers to other similar questions said that it is not possible - but did not mention that it was possible in Chrome - so I am hoping that someone could tweak what I have here to make it work in FireFox and IE10.

### Desired outcome:

A container div that takes up 100% height - but no more.
Which wraps header and footer divs whose heights are determined by their content.
The footer div is always flush with the bottom of the page.
A middle div which stretches between the header and footer. If its content overflows it should scroll.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7ddc.png

### Current implementation:

CSS:

```css
html,
body {
   height:100%;
   margin:0;
}
#container {
   display:table;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}
#header,
#footer {
   display:table-row;
   background-color:#FC0;
   height:2px;
}
#middle {
   display:table-row;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}
#content {
   height:100%;
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">header<br/>header line 2<br/></div>
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="content">Burrow under covers...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

This works in Chrome, but in IE and Firefox if the content is larger than the middle div the container becomes larger than 100% high and the page obtains a scroll bar.

Comment: your `overflow-y:scroll;` should be on `#middle`, not `#content`.

Comment: @PlantTheldea that breaks the functionality in Chrome and does not fix the problem in Firefox or IE. http://jsfiddle.net/EtNgv/1/
Perhaps I didn't explain something well enough. The footer should always align to the bottom of the page and the document should never be larger than 100% height.

Comment: Webkit seems to calculate the height of #middle based on 100% height - the content determined height of the header and footer. Then the height of the content div is determined by the height of #middle. In FF and IE the height of the content seems to determine the height of #middle - despite height:100% and overflow-y:scroll being set. What other styles can determine the order of calculations for div heights? I tried different table-layouts. I tried overflow:hidden on #content. I tried making #content a table-cell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got close, but it still feels kinda sloppy.  I can't imagine creating a page like this without using jQuery to determine the height of the screen, #footer, #header, etc...

```
Forked Fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mRDux/

Comment: Thanks. In IE the footer div overlaps the middle div.  This is not what I was looking for unfortunately. Impressed with the expanded Catipsum though.

Comment: It is trivial using Javascript - but I would like to find a CSS solution. It may not be possible - but it is frustrating that it actually can work in Chrome. It makes me think there may be a way to make it work in FF and IE.