# CSS and html with dynamic header,footer and content

Tags: html, css

I'am trying to have header,content and footer as dynamic fields. Tried a lot of different solutions, and it must work in multiply instances. I need a the scroller only in content area, so I haven't used absolute zero on the footer. But uses table layout.

If you look at the code snippet, you can see that the content #wrapper(yellow)  have the same size as content. But I can't get the scoller when content (#overflow, black) get heigher than the wrapper.

I know a little script can solve this, but is it possible just With CSS??

The link below is something simular but there is no good answer. Maybe this can be, If it is possible to get a working scroller in content area.

[CSS 100% height layout. Fluid header, footer and content. In IE10 and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368452/css-100-height-layout-fluid-header-footer-and-content-in-ie10-and-firefox)

```html
<style>
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #wrap {
        height: 150px;
        width: 400px;
        display:table;
        position:absolute;
        text-align:center;
        table-layout:fixed;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    #header{
        display:table-row;
        border:1px solid red;
        background:green;
    }
    #content{
        height: 100%;
        background:blue;        
        display:table-cell;
    }
    #wrapper{
        width:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        border:10px solid yellow;
        position:relative;
        overflow:scroll;
        display:block;
    }
    #footer{
        width: 100%;        
        display:table-row;
        background:green;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
            HEADER
        </div>        
        <div id="content">
           <div id="wrapper">
               <div id="overflow" style="height:50px;width:1px;border:10px solid black;"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specificy a height for the wrapper element

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    /*min-height:100%;*/
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:10px solid yellow;
    position:relative;
    overflow:scroll;
    display:block;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bellu/yur8xshw/1/) the working Fiddle with your example.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I really want it to be dynamic. If I resize  main div (#wrap), then Your static value will be wrong. I'am tring to get less codes...

Comment: If you resize vertically the #wrap?

Comment: Of course, both ways. It will be used for user resize, drag and drop. Including nesting.. I hope I can use it similar to a window on a computer....